# what are Mixins in the React.js framework?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am reading Reactjs documentation and came across mixins,but i dont understand mixins clearly.What are mixins and what are they used for?

Comment: Not an answer but, if you're new to React and asking about mixins, [Mixins Are Dead](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.bcdftwarc) is worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link that will explain the concept in more detail.

https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/

"Mixins are a great compromise, allowing entire functional units to be borrowed and accessed with minimal syntax and they play very well with prototypes. They offer the descriptive prowess of hierarchical inheritance without the brain-cracking issues associated with multi-tiered, single-rooted ancestry."